# How are views counted?

Tags: support, view-counter

When I see that a question has, say, 100 views, how should I understand it? Is it the number of distinct users that viewed the question or the number of distinct views regardless of the viewers? Are my views counted?

Comment: Oh, as usual, I have read your question wrongly! So, I am deleting my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a question on MSO that explains how views are counted:

[How does Stack Overflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

While there are no SE employees on the thread, Jeff Atwood has closed some questions as dupes of that one ([e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40909/how-are-view-counts-calculated)), so presumably it is not too far off from the truth.